# sum of an array elements in cpp return wrong value

Tags: c++, arrays, function

I tried to write a simple code to calculate an array elements' sum. every thing looks normal but  the function return the sum value wrongly (it always multiply it by two). Although if I want just print the value, it works fine.
this is the code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void getElements(int[],int);
int sumOfElements(int[],int);

int number;
int sum=0;
int main()
{
   int a[10];
    getElements(a,5);
    sumOfElements(a,5);
   cout<<"The sum is "<<sumOfElements(a,5)<<endl;
    return 0;
}



//Getting  array's elements

void getElements(int numbers[],int size_)
{
    for (int i=0; i<size_; i++)
    {
        cout<<"numbers["<<i<<"]: ";
        cin>>number;
        numbers[i]=number;
    }
    cout<<'\n';
}
//Calculation the sum of array's elements
int sumOfElements(int numbers[],int size_)
{
    for(int i=0;i<size_;i++)
        {
            sum+=numbers[i];
        }
        cout<<sum<<endl;
    return sum;

}
```

any idea? thank you in advance!

Comment: calling `sumOfElements` modifies the global variable `sum` ... and you call `sumOfElements` twice.  so... yeah...you're gonna have a double sum.  Probably should have declared `sum` local to `sumOfElements`.

Comment: Now I got it! Thanks.

Comment: as alluded to, it's better practice to scope variables only where they're needed. You should move `int number` into `getElements` and `int sum` into `sumOfElements`. Then in `main`, you can capture the return value of `sumOfElements` and print it out, or print out the return value directly as you have done. After that change, you can call `sumOfElements` 10 times if you want and it will always return the same, correct sum "automatically". Furthermore, calling it without capturing its return value would essentially be a noop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined `int sum` globally and were calling `sumOfElements`twice, so sum contained twice what you expected.

Here is a modified version of your code that does what you want:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void getElements(int[], int);
int sumOfElements(int[], int);

int main() {
  int numbers[5];
  getElements(numbers, 5);
  cout << sumOfElements(numbers, 5);
  return 0;
}

void getElements(int numbers[], int size) {
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    cin >> numbers[i];
  }
}

int sumOfElements(int numbers[], int size) {
  int sum = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    sum += numbers[i];
  }
  return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a modified and simpler version of your program:

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    const int num_elements_to_sum = 5;
    array<int, num_elements_to_sum> elements;
    for(int i=0; i<num_elements_to_sum; ++i){
        cin>>elements[i];
    }
    int sum = accumulate(elements.begin(), elements.end(), 0);
    cout<<"Sum: "<<sum<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

C++ has a dedicated fixed size `array` container, use this instead of C-style arrays. This then allows to use standard library algorithms instead of your own implementation (e.g. `accumulate`).